# Delete all cookie with same name and different path

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

i'm using codeigniter and i have all the routes like this

```
 www.example.com/path1/
 www.example.com/path1/path_/
```

In every page i do a control if SESSION['lang'] is set.
if it's set I also set the Cookie

```
setcookie("lang", $_SESSION["LANG"], time() + (60* 60 * 24 * 30 *12 *20),  "./");
```

But i have a problem...
when I do Logout from admin area I must delete the session and also the cookie.
But if i Delete a cookie in this way

```
setcookie("lang",'', time() - (60* 60 * 24 * 30 *12 *20),  "./");
```

it will delete only one cookie lang.
I must delete all cookie "lang" of different path.

Someone can help me?!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to set so many cookies? You are already using sessions, why can't you store this data there?

Comment: Yes...because when a user Close the web browser i want to remember the last Language choose...also because My Application do authentication without username and password but only with a cookie setted...if there is a cookie I must set the relative session and after I use only this

Comment: It seems as if you should only need one cookie set with the path "/". There is actually a limit on how much cookie data can be sent in a request.

Comment: YES...
But if I set a cookie when i'm in www.example.com/path/ in this way
      setcookie("lang", $_SESSION["LANG"], time() + (60* 60 * 24 * 30 *12 *20),  "/"); 
when i go to see in Chrome Info the cookie is set with path equal to /path/

I need to know how set only one cookie name for my domain or for the parent path

Answer (score 2):

To set a global cookie for the entire site the path should be "/" without the dot.

"/" means the root of the website.

"./" means current directory.

In your case to set the global cookie it should be:

```
setcookie("lang", $_SESSION["LANG"], time() + (60* 60 * 24 * 30 *12 *20),  "/");
```

To delete the global cookie:

```
setcookie("lang",'', 1,  "/");
```

Regarding your actual question, "Delete all cookie with same name and different path" there is no official documented way to do it. There is a hack using the $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] variable like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146196/how-to-delete-all-cookies-with-the-same-name?rq=1). 
But this variable is not documented and could be non existent on some servers.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has a method to delete cookies

```
delete_cookie()
```

Lets you delete a cookie. Unless you've set a custom path or other values, only the name of the cookie is needed:

```
delete_cookie("name");
```

This function is otherwise identical to set_cookie(), except that it does not have the value and expiration parameters. You can submit an array of values in the first parameter or you can set discrete parameters.

```
delete_cookie($name, $domain, $path, $prefix)
```

With this function you can delete the cookie of any path or domain. Perhaps you need to write this function so many times as "domain/path" you have

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

The way which you use to set a cookie stores a separate cookie for each page/URL that you visit because:

```
setcookie(..., ..., ..., "./"); // the 4th parameter means "this directory"
```

So if the script get executed on every page then every directory and subdirectory that you visit will get a separate cookie. However, this is not necessary if you want to set the "lang" parameter for a whole part of the domain.

If you change it to something like "/foo/" then this cookie will be valid for any http://www.example.com/foo/ and any subdirectory of www.example.com/foo/, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php:

> **Path**
>
> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If
>   set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If
>   set to **'/foo/'**, the cookie will only be available within the **/foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain**. The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.

Because this will store only one cookie for the whole part of the domain, you can easily invalidate it using your code with the 4th parameter changed:

```
setcookie(..., ..., ...,  "/foo/");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Tom... I Know How using cookie...but i don't understand How set only one cookie For My domain...for example i'm in www.ex.com/path1/path i want to set a cookie in www.ex.com only...